# Convert HTML TABLE to HTML5 TABLE with CSS and Default

Tags: html, css

I was reading that HTML table values like

```
border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
```

are no longer supported in HTML5 so I want to "convert" a table to HTML5 using CSS values. But here is a example about `border-colapse`, a guy says its default is `border-colapse:colapse` is that true? What other values are default?

What I need is a table like this converted to HTML5 with CSS

```
<table width="80%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Reading on many sites I believe the correct way to convert this is like this:

```
<table style="
width:80%; 
margin: 0 auto; 
border-spacing:0; 
border-collapse:collapse;
border:0;">

  <tr style="border-spacing:0; border-collapse:collapse; border:0;">
```

to avoid spaces between TDs like this

```
    <td style="border-spacing:0; 
border-collapse:collapse;
border:0;"> testing 1 </td>

    <td style="border-spacing:0; 
border-collapse:collapse;
border:0;"> testing 2 </td> 

 <td style="border-spacing:0; 
border-collapse:collapse;
border:0;"> testing 3 </td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

Is this correct or I must add something more or delete something?

The question is: if the browsers CSS set some default maybe I do not need to add all that. How to convert the old HTML to HTML 5 table?

I do need tables for this, already tested using DIVs but for my case I need tables

EDIT
Does I need to add

```
border-spacing:0; 
border-collapse:collapse;
border:0;
```

To TABLE, TR AND TD ?

Comment: Yes, what you have is correct(although somewhat unnecessary as you are defining default table stylings that would exist without specifying CSS). That said, I would advise against using inline CSS. Instead you should have an external stylesheet or just a single set of `style` tags to define these styles.

Comment: `display: table` on a `<table>`, `display: table-row` on a `<tr>`, and `display: table-cell` on `<td>` are redundant, those are the default `display` properties of those elements.

Comment: Edited: Does I need to add border-spacing:0; border-collapse:collapse;
border:0; to TABLE, TR AND TD ?

Comment: I would say the CSS solution is for HTML4 too.

Comment: border-spacing only applies to elements with `display:table` and `display:inline-table`, so it does nothing on tr and td elements that have their default display settings.

Answer (score 0):

You could use CSS **Flexbox** or **Grid** to create this table.

In my below sample I used Flexbox and compared it to the old HTML table way.

One of the benefits to use Flexbox or Grid instead of Table is that you can manage the responsiveness more easily.

I have been inspired by this YouTube tutorial (it's a long one but you have to go where it interests you, I advise you to start at 23 minutes and 20 seconds, the beginning doesn't matter that much): https://youtu.be/EKXCO1iBnpo?t=1399

```css
td, .flex-item {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 5px;
}
.flex-item {
    flex-basis: 40%;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
td img, .flex-container img {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .flex-container {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
}
```

```html
<h1>TABLE:</h1>

<table>
    <tbody>

        <tr>
            <td style="width: 50%;">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/120x170.png" alt="" />
                <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                </p>
            </td>

            <td style="width: 50%;">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/120x170.png" alt="" />
                <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td style="width: 50%;">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/120x170.png" alt="" />
                <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                </p>
            </td>

            <td style="width: 50%;">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/120x170.png" alt="" />
                <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>


<h1>FLEXBOX:</h1>
<div class="flex-container">

    <div class="flex-item">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/120x170.png" alt="" />
        <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        </p>    
    </div>

    <div class="flex-item">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/120x170.png" alt="" />
        <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        </p>    
    </div>

    <div class="flex-item">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/120x170.png" alt="" />
        <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        </p>    
    </div>

    <div class="flex-item">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/120x170.png" alt="" />
        <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        </p>    
    </div>

</div>
```